# CSV path with Samba Grafana Dashboard

Tags: csv, grafana, samba

I have a device, this device will store real-time data with format CSV into a samba folder that can be accessed with Windows. I can access this samba folder with format \IP_ADDRESS\SHARED_FOLDER\Destination.csv

What I want to do is, Is it possible for CSV Plugin Datasource to consume CSV files from the samba folder? Or is there any possible way that I can choose to do this one?

Comment: Store "real time data" into a database instead

Answer (score 0):

By using official CSV plugin, try */IP_ADDRESS/SHARED_FOLDER/Destination.csv*

Because \ does not work in Grafana's CSV plugin.
(I'm using Windows 10 to run Grafana server)